# How to export the result of Jupyter cell to .py file

Tags: python, jupyter

How can I save the results of print (Python 2) in a Jupyter cell (the cell just contains:

```
print project #where project is a very long dictionary
```

..to a .py file?

Comment: Open a file, and write to it

Answer (score 2):

**edit**

to a pyfile? A dictionary is normally saved in json format.

Use the json library:

```
import json

with open("output.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(project,f) #
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, just need to change the extension to .py so I can load it to the software that uses it as input.

Comment: @Pegaso Extensions don't really matter. You're saving json, so you'd save to a json file